# OSX: Thousands of fonts

Tags: font-management, osx

How can I access the thousands of font files on my Mac without "installing" them and thereby slowing the machine to a crawl?

Comment: without installing them what you want to access??? you can see them by double clicking i guess,but if you want to use them you have to install them...\

Comment: I'd encourage you to NOT have a thousand fonts. Most good designers will use a core set of a few dozen workhorses and then selectively install one-offs as needed per project.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with GD. Seems it would be more at home on SU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2756/creating-a-list-of-favourite-fonts-in-photoshop/2761#2761):

You need **a font management tool** of some kind to help you organize your fonts into sets of your liking. There are a number of them out there; [Extensis Suitcase Fusion](http://www.extensis.com/en/products/suitcasefusion3/overview.jsp) and [FontXplorer Pro](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/pro/) come to mind.

From the FontXplorer website...

> **Is font management for you?** Font
>   management is for anyone who uses more
>   than just a handful of fonts.
>
> Ask yourself these questions:
>
> **Do you need to free up your system?**
>   Every font that has been activated on
>   your system requires the deployment of
>   system resources to applications. This
>   can be an unproductive use of
>   resources, particularly for fonts that
>   are used infrequently. Font management
>   allows you to activate fonts solely
>   for the period of time you actually
>   need them, freeing up precious
>   resources so your system can run more
>   efficiently.
>
> **Do you have trouble maintaining an
>   overview of your fonts?** Every
>   professional creative application you
>   install adds new fonts to your system
>   that you may or may not want. Font
>   management helps you find, preview,
>   and sort fonts and deactivate the ones
>   you don’t need.